# Using the Wikipedia API to retrieve the list of contents from a page

Tags: rest, api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I want to extract the list of disciplines from this wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_academic_disciplines, and I want to know how can I do it using the Wikipedia API.

I tried as following : https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=List_of_action_films_of_the_2010s&contentmodel=wikitext&prop=wikitext&format=json

but this only retrieve the first section of the article, and I want to retrieve the section of Contents, so the result would look something like this :

```
{
Arts : {
"Performing Arts" : [all its sub-child],
"Visual arts" : [all its sub-child]
}
Geography: {....}

}
```

Is this possible using the Wikipedia API ?

Answer (score 2):

[action=parse&format=json&page=Outline_of_academic_disciplines&prop=sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&page=Outline_of_academic_disciplines&prop=sections):

```
"sections": [
        {
            "toclevel": 1,
            "level": "2",
            "line": "Arts",
            "number": "1",
            "index": "1",
            "fromtitle": "Outline_of_academic_disciplines",
            "byteoffset": 1241,
            "anchor": "Arts"
        },
        {
            "toclevel": 2,
            "level": "3",
            "line": "Performing arts",
            "number": "1.1",
            "index": "2",
            "fromtitle": "Outline_of_academic_disciplines",
            "byteoffset": 1279,
            "anchor": "Performing_arts"
        },
        ...
```